# Testing Login Redirects

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

I've been trying to implement a user profile system in Django that allows you to simply request "/profile/" as the url to redirect to your user profile if logged in and to the login page if not.

The test is written as follows

```
class LoggedInProfileTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='Milhouse',
            email="milhouse@gmail.com",
            password="MilhousePW")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.user.delete()

    def test_user_profile_redirect(self):
        request = self.factory.get("/profile/")
        request.user = self.user
        response = profile_redirect(request)
        self.assertRedirects(
            response,
            expected_url="/profile/Milhouse/")
```

The actually functions properly and redirects as desired but the test refuses to pass with the following error thrown.

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'client'
```

URL routing code

```
# main urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^profile/', include('profiles.urls')),
    ...
]

# profiles.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w+-.@]+)/$',
        views.user_profile,
        name="user_profile"),
    url(r'^$',
        views.profile_redirect,
        name="profile_redirect")
]
```

Views code

```
@login_required
def profile_redirect(request):
    return redirect("user_profile", request.user.username)


def user_profile(request, username):
    pass
```

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Haven't used unittest in a while (fan of py.test) but shouldn't you be using the TestClient provided by TestCase? You should be able to access it as `self.client` from any method in your test class. Not sure if it might help with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Sebastian. Indeed I should've :). I wanted to fiddle around with the RequestFactory to get familiar with it but maybe it's a bit overkill for these tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used `client` provided by Testcase.

First you need to create a user for testing in the database. You should do this explicitly in you test code.

Let's assume that the user you want to login in the test case has a username `username` and a password `password`. Then you can do the following:

```
self.client.login(username=username, password=password) # This do the login work
response = self.client.get('/profile')
# here do your assert work
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sunhs you hit it on the head! Apparently RequestFactory doesn't play nice with sessions which does a number on any login testing. Thanks for the help sunhs and @Sebastian :)